# How to get the IP address of the host that i have ssh'ed into?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, linux-networking, terminal

I have ssh'ed into a linux host with
`ssh username@ip`.

Once logged on, how do I get the IP address of the host?

commands such as `host name -I` or `ifconfig` are returning an IP address that are different than the address that I connected to.

How to get this information?

This will help me get what is the IP I have to type if I have to ssh into any system.

The IP I ssh into is 10.49.x.xxx. I am connected via LAN. The server may be via Internet as the server is accessed across location. I think the connection is NAT.

Comment: You can't. Due to NAT there may be *very* differing relationships between hosts and IP's, and furthermore one IP can map to multiple hosts.

Comment: I originally received the IP from my team(don't know how they got). So how the original admin then found it? There has to be someway isn't it?

Comment: Probably. *Why* you want it? What problem do you have? You were told the IP to connect and then connected, that assumes the address you typed is configured to accept such a connection *somehow*. If you want to know *exactly how* it is configured that way, you have to ask for a network configuration — and not on the public place, we can't possibly know how your network is set up. Read your internal documentation. Or investigate yourself, connect to the involved networking hardware and observe the configuration, especially NAT and various TCP forwarding techniques.

Comment: It's kind of like making a cake: if you have the recipe it's fairly easy to figure out things. If you don't, it's hard to guess the exact process by tasting the cake. The recipe is in this case the network configuration.

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov. For me the application is I want to ssh from that server(destination machine) to my machine, basically reverse. But I don't know the ip of my machine that the ssh will allow.

Comment: That is what you have to ask: how to provide a reverse connection. And, most probably it's **totally independent** from how you connect there, mostly depending on how your computer is connected to the Internet. One way I can suggest, for the case the reverse connection to be possible while you are forward connected: use ssh TCP port forwarding (see `man ssh` option `-R` and `man ssh_config` option `RemoteForward`).

Comment: Your question lacks any information at all about this network. Edit it to add: the servers IP address and net, and the client,  any NATs or firewalls in between, and whether this is over the internet.

Comment: this question is just blanty offtopic - ask the IT Department or if your the end customer, contact the Original Owner and/or create a support ticket

Answer (score -1):

As @vidarlo already stated, this can not be done 100% reliably - however I think I can answer the question you might actually have:

Lets assume that you ssh-ed into an ec2 instance on amazon aws, which doesn't show its public ip in `ifconfig` or `ip addr show`, then you could use something like `curl https://ifconfig.me` to get the IP address that it uses to talk to the internet. This command will contact the website https://ifconfig.me, which will return the IP address it received the request from. As @vidarlo stated however, the ec2 instance might have multiple public IPs routed to it, so that doesnt answer your question 100%. You could have used a different IP to ssh to it.

From my belly feeling this might answer your question though.

There is one hacky answer to your question ;) You never stated that you can ONLY get this IP on the machine that you logged in to - if not you can just check your process list on your workstation ;)

`user@workstation:~$ ps aux | grep ssh`

My belly feeling tells me this is not what you wanted though ;)

Comment: this may work from a consumer sight, but not if the traffic is re-routed depending on the kind of request.